# Dealing with a high DPI display

Tags: xubuntu, dpi

I recently purchased and installed Xubuntu 17.04 on it.  Aside from some Secure boot finagling, it seems to be running fine, but the DPI is super tiny.  I'm running a 1080p resolution on a 14in monitor.  In XFCE I was able to change the DPI to be 128 instead of the standard 96.  But when using Chrome things are still super tiny.

Is there some package on apt I could install to help with this?